# Show all final 2-digit numbers of the decimal expansions of squares are to be found among those of $0^2, 1^2,...25^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not really sure where to begin. The first part of the question states that "every positive integer has a unique representation in the form $50k+l$, with $-24\lt l \le 25$," which isn't even true, so...

Comment: Notice that $50k+l$ for $-24<l\leq25$ creates an interval $X_k = (50k-24, 50k+25]$ assuming $k \in \mathbb{N}$. If every interval is disjoint and the union of these $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is a subset of the union of all the sets then it seems like this would be true.

Comment: someone pointed out that it would be impossible to write 26 with these restrictions.

Comment: correct, it seems it may have meant $-24 \leq l \leq 25$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you square $50k+l$ what do you get?